# Changing Printer Trays During Print Job

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, printing

Is there a way to switch printer trays during a print job? I've been asked to put together a pick/pack slip program. They want the inventory pick slip to be printed on a sheet of colored paper, the pack slips to be on white paper, and they want it properly collated (pick, pack, pack, pack, pack; pick, pack, pack, pack, pack; ...).

I found some other threads on setting default trays, but didn't find anything on alternating trays during the job. Maybe I'm not searching on the right thing.

Don't know if it makes a difference, but our printer is an HP 3015n and the clients will be both XP and Win 7 Pro.

Comment: abatishchev - saw you edited my post. Are the development environment and programming language not relevant?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6iXuU4b5mh4&t=25s ? :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try something like this you have to reference `System.Drawing.dll` from the projects --> Reference--> Add

```
//Namespace:  System.Drawing.Printing
//Assembly:  System.Drawing (in System.Drawing.dll)

PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();
PaperSize oPS = new PaperSize();
oPS.RawKind = (int)PaperKind.A4;
PaperSource oPSource = new PaperSource();
oPSource.RawKind = (int) PaperSourceKind.Upper;

printDoc.PrinterSettings = new PrinterSettings();
printDoc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = sPrinterName;
printDoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = oPS;
printDoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSource = oPSource;
printDoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(printDoc_PrintPage);
printDoc.Print();
printDoc.Dispose();
```

Comment: So, essentially I would be creating hundreds of mini print runs and changing the paper source between jobs?

Comment: Haven't had a chance to test and see if it works, but it may, and is further than I made it on my own. Since no one else has commented in a couple days I'll mark as answer. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I can't get this approach to work to change trays within the same job. I change trays in printDoc_PrintPage. It appears to ignore that change... Any chance of a fully working implementation?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge no - you have to submit 2 jobs on a queue that basically only you use.

Comment: Not sure I follow, could you elaborate? Thanks.

Comment: what is the name of the Paper Kind for the 2 different Trays

Comment: Not sure what you mean by Paper Kind? Tray 1 would be colored 8.5x11, Tray 2 would be white 8.5x11.

Comment: http://www.textcontrol.com/en_US/downloads/library/snippet/papersource/ check this link out it's a better example

Comment: Let me know if this works or worked for you I am interested in knowing.. there are alot of individuals on here whom have asked similar question and perhaps this site will be the do all that they are looking for so to speak

Answer (score -1):

You can change printer tray with this code.

```
string _paperSource = "TRAY 2"; // Printer Tray
string _paperName = "8x17"; // Printer paper name

//Tested code comment. The commented code was the one I tested, but when 
//I was writing the post I realized that could be done with less code.

//PaperSize pSize = new PaperSize()  //Tested code :)
//PaperSource pSource = new PaperSource(); //Tested code :)

/// Find selected paperSource and paperName.
foreach (PaperSource _pSource in printDoc.PrinterSettings.PaperSources)
{
    if (_pSource.SourceName.ToUpper() == _paperSource.ToUpper())
    {
        printDoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSource = _pSource;
        //pSource = _pSource; //Tested code :)
        break;
    }
}

foreach (PaperSize _pSize in printDoc.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes)
{
    if (_pSize.PaperName.ToUpper() == _paperName.ToUpper())
    {
        printDoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = _pSize;
        //pSize = _pSize; //Tested code :)
        break;
    }
}

//printDoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = pSize; //Tested code :)
//printDoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSource = pSource;    //Tested code :)
```